# Run Filezilla Client in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with one public subnet and one private.
The public subnet has an OpenVpn Server (worked also as NAT) and a public IP
The private subnet has a Win 2012R2 Server with an Oracle 11g server.
My set up:
1. VPC:
[image: VPC]
2. Public Subnet:
[image: Public subnet]
3. Private Subnet:
[image: Private subnet]
4. Internet gateway
[image: Gateway] 
5. Security Groups:
   5a: For the VPN server:
   [image: VPN security]
   5b: For the Win Server (with the oracle server)
   [image: Win security]

So, I've set up the OpenVPN server and I am able to connect to the server from my laptop. Everything is fine.
Now I want to run FileZilla in my Win Server to download some files from ftp sites. 
I add more security groups to my Win Server with inbound and outbound rules but it doesn't work. I think that I have to add a route table for my private subnet to connect to outside world, but I have no idea how to implement that.

Rules that I have tried (inbound and outbound):
[image: Extra rules]

Route table that I tried:
[image: Route table]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could the person who downvoted my question to leave a comment with the reason. I would love to learn and be better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you open a browser on the Windows server and view Internet sites? I'd start by getting that working before moving on to FileZilla. If you truly have your OpenVPN server also working as a NAT server then it should be providing internet access for the instances in the private subnet.  You shouldn't need to open any inbound rules in the security group (because you aren't running an FTP/SFTP server, just a client), and you should be able to leave the outbound rules as default (which allow all outbound traffic).

It appears that you are missing a route table entry for your NAT gateway, so your OpenVPN server is not currently acting as a NAT gateway. You will have to configure a NAT Instance or an AWS managed NAT Gateway in order to allow instances in your private subnet to access the Internet. You should [read the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat.html).

Comment: I can't open a browser. I'll try your suggestion with the route and the rules

Comment: Why can't you open a browser on your Windows server?

Comment: I managed to have internet access and successfully connected to the FTP. The answer was to attach a NAT gateway in public subnet and point all the traffic from the private subnet to this gateway.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to create a Bastion Server in your Public Subnet to make that File Zilla to work. Check below guide.

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3N8GFK85UN1G6/Securely-connect-to-Linux-instances-running-in-a-private-Amazon-VPC

Comment: I don't think this is correct. He has an OpenVPN server, which is serving the same purpose as a bastion server.

Comment: I am not a network person and most of these are new to me. So I am not sure if this is a correct solution or not, but it looks complicate to me.

Comment: The link provided in this answer is related to "How to connect private EC2 instance", It has nothing to do with Filezilla.